# MPChart BarChart X-Axis label issue

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have implemented MPChart library's BarChart.

When the number of bars in the bar chart are below 9, the labels are aligned to the bars but once the count increases above 9, the labels get skipped and instead of 9 labels on the x - axis it shows only 4-5.
Truncating the label string size doesn't help.

Screenshots:
[image]
[image]

My code:

```
            float index = 0;
            ArrayList<String> xAxisLabel = new ArrayList<>();

            for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> callMapVal : callMap.entrySet()) {
                if (index < 8) {
                    barChartEntries.add(new BarEntry(index, callMapVal.getValue()));
                    if (callMapVal.getKey().length() > 10) {
                        xAxisLabel.add(getTruncated(callMapVal.getKey(), 9));
                    } else {
                        xAxisLabel.add(callMapVal.getKey());
                    }

                }
                index++;
            }

            BarDataSet dataSet = new BarDataSet(barChartEntries, selectedCallType.toString() + " CALLS");
            dataSet.setValueTextSize(8f);
            BarData chartData = new BarData(dataSet);
            dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
            barChart.setData(chartData);
            barChart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new IndexAxisValueFormatter(xAxisLabel));
            //barChart.getXAxis().setLabelRotationAngle(20f);
            barChart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
            barChart.getXAxis().setTextSize(8f);
            //barChart.getXAxis().setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
            barChart.getXAxis().setGranularityEnabled(true);
            barChart.getXAxis().setCenterAxisLabels(false);
            barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
            barChart.setFitBars(true); // make the x-axis fit exactly all bars
            barChart.invalidate(); // refresh
            barChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
            barChart.setDoubleTapToZoomEnabled(false);
            barChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));           
            barChart.setDrawBorders(false);
            barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
```

Comment: `getTruncated` remove this and try.

Comment: I'm using that method to reduce the label size, it doesn't affect the chart. The params to this method is (String,StringSize)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the label count to the number of bars in your chart:

```
barChart.getXAxis().setLabelCount(9, true);
```

Comment: I tried the same but the behavior is the same, if count of bars is =>9 setting the label count still causes labels to be skipped.

Comment: Versions prior to 3.0 require you to call `setLabelsToSkip(0)` instead, you can try that. Both versions do not work for values greater than or equal to 9?

Comment: I'm on the latest version 3.0.3, do i use setLabelToSkip with setLabelCount?

Comment: The version 3.0.3 doesn't have the method setLabelsToSkip ()